# hibernate+JPA+Spring+Mysql won't drop the table

Tags: nhibernate, jpa

I have my application using hibernate+JPA+Spring+Mysql, each time i run the application, there are more data added to the table, when i checked it's the same data add again and again to the tables. though i defined:

```
persistence_unit=data-mysql-create
```

in my config file. i assume that would drop the tables first then create new data in the table, right? but seemed it didn't work that way. the following are some other configurations i have:

applicationContext.xml:

```
  <!-- The shared JPA entity manager factory. -->
  <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="javax.persistence.Persistence"
    factory-method="createEntityManagerFactory" destroy-method="close"
    scope="singleton">
    <constructor-arg value="${persistence_unit}" />
    <constructor-arg>
      <util:map>
        <entry key="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="${db_url}" />
        <entry key="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="${db_user}" />
        <entry key="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="${db_password}" />
        <entry key="hibernate.search.default.indexBase" value="${lucene_index_directory}" />
      </util:map>
    </constructor-arg>
  </bean>

  <!-- The data repository. -->
  <bean id="dataRepository" class="com.xyz.news.api.JPADataRepository">
    <constructor-arg ref="entityManagerFactory" />
  </bean>
```

persistence.xml:

```
  <persistence-unit name="data-mysql-create" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <class>com.xyz.news.model.Data</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="news" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="news" />
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="com.xyz.news.rdb.NewsMySQLDialect" />
      <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="3" />
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
      <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider" />
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="100" />
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="1" />
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="1" />
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="60" />
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="0" />
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="30" />
      <property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider" value="org.hibernate.search.store.FSDirectoryProvider" />
      <property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase" value="lucene/indexes" />
    </properties>
      </persistence-unit>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are using `HibernatePersistence` provider ?

I think the way you have it specified means that anything found on classpath witch implements
`javax.persistence.Persistence` can be used as a provider (ElcipseLink, Hibernate...).

If you want to be sure Hibernate is used try to configure `jpaVendorAdapter` and set it to
`<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">`.

You can then turn on TRACE level on your log4j.properties (`org.hibernate=TRACE`, sorry i do not remember excatly the class where the actual loaded properties are printed, so it will be a LOT of log messages) and check the output for `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` string, it shoudl be on the very beginning when the `EntityManagerFactory` is being instantiated.